# How to use negative margin in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create an element that has a fixed background image that has a element that is then placed over the background image using negative margin.

I am trying to figure out the best way to set the height of `billboard__image` knowing that it will be dynamic based on the browser width, and then use negative padding on the `billboard_content` to have those elements move up over the background image.

I am also using bootstrap 4.3.1:

```css
.section {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.billboard {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.billboard__image {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.billboard__image::after {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 33.3333333333%;
  display: block;
}

.billboard__image--fixed {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.billboard__content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: -50% 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.billboard__content--video {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.billboard__content--video h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}

.billboard__content--video .embed-responsive {
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section billboard">
  <div class="billboard__image billboard__image--fixed" style="background-image:url('https://www.rollingstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/fleetwood-mac-new-lineup-first-picture-2018-77e1da91-6a10-46d3-8b48-a203c150139c.jpg?resize=1800,1200&w=1200')">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="billboard__content billboard__content--video">
      <h3>Fleetwood Mac</h3>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wLSUDSNqLgQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
```

Here is my example in a fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/zeropsi/Lkbhs41x/.

Any thoughts for the best way to have the content box be responsive in negative space without moving above the background image?

**Edit**: Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

Comment: can you make a sketch drawing about the wanted design. I have troubles to imagine how you want it to look like

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you're trying to achieve? Also, negative padding does not exist.

Comment: @tacoshy yes - I will create an image real quick.

Comment: @disinfor - sorry, I got ahead of myself, I meant negative margins.

Comment: @tacoshy - if you run the code snippet above in full screen you should see what I am talking about. In full screen, the layout looks as expected, but once you shrink the screen down you can see how the video starts to move above the background image.

Comment: @disinfor - please see above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tacoshy - I have edited the original post and included an image.